# not able to connect to elastic-search container from the zipkin container

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, docker-network, zipkin

I am running two containers using docker-compose files

The zipkin container is created as below

```
# zipkin/Dockerfile
FROM openzipkin/zipkin

USER root

USER 1001

EXPOSE 9411
```

and

```
# zipkin/docker-compose.yaml
version: "3.8"

# This file is used for running the service locally

networks:
 kong-net:
  name: my-net
  driver: bridge
  ipam:
    config:
      - subnet: 172.1.1.0/24

services:
  zipkin-local:
    container_name: zipkin-local
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      my-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.1.1.18
    ports:
      - "9411:9411"
```

note that the network is `my-net` and the ipv4 is `172.1.1.18`

and I run `docker-compose up --build` in the zipkin directory

The elastic search is created as below

```
# elk/Dockerfile
FROM sebp/elk
```

and

```
# elk/docker-compose.yaml
version: "3.8"

networks:
 kong-net:
  name: my-net
  driver: bridge
  ipam:
    config:
      - subnet: 172.1.1.0/24

services:
  elk-local:
    container_name: elk-local
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      kong-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.1.1.38
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
      - "9200:9200"
      - "5044:5044"
```

note that the network is `my-net` and the ipv4 is `172.1.1.38`
and I run `docker-compose up --build` in the elk directory

Now I send a get request to

- http://127.0.0.1:9200/, it returns a json response
- http://127.0.0.1:9411/zipkin/, it shows the zipkin ui

but when I enter the containers

- `docker exec -it zipkin-local bash`
- `docker exec -it elk-local bash`

inside the `elk-local` container I run

- `curl http://127.0.0.1:9200` and it returns a proper response

```
{
  "name" : "elk",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "SUSNP9w7SbqKiuSoCPIl2w",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "8.1.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "3700f7679f7d95e36da0b43762189bab189bc53a",
    "build_date" : "2022-03-03T14:20:00.690422633Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "9.0.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.17.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "7.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

- `curl http://zipkin-local:9411/zipkin` and it returns nothing

inside the `zipkin-local` container I run

- `curl http://127.0.0.1:/zipkin` it returns

```
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Redirection</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY><H1>Redirect</H1></BODY>
```

- `curl http://127.0.0.1:/zipkin` it returns

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Network Error</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big><strong>MY COMPANY NAME - Device *****</strong></big><BR>
</FONT>
<blockquote>
<TABLE border=0 cellPadding=1 width="80%">
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big>Network Error (dns_server_failure)</big>
<BR>
<BR>
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
Your request could not be processed because an error occurred contacting the DNS server.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
The DNS server may be temporarily unavailable, or there could be a network problem.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica" SIZE=2>
<BR>
For assistance, contact your network support team.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
</blockquote>
</FONT>
</BODY></HTML>
```

I have another container in the same docker network and from that one I can run

- `curl http://elk-local:9200`

It returns the proper response

```
{
  "name" : "elk",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "SUSNP9w7SbqKiuSoCPIl2w",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "8.1.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "3700f7679f7d95e36da0b43762189bab189bc53a",
    "build_date" : "2022-03-03T14:20:00.690422633Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "9.0.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.17.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "7.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

So there is a problem with zipkin but I do not understand what.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Manually declaring two separate Docker networks with the same CIDR block seems like it shouldn't work.  Can you delete all of the `networks:` blocks in both files, including all of the manual IP-address assignment, so each Compose file has its own `default` network and they don't conflict?  Do the two services need to talk to each other, and if so, can they move into the same Compose file?  Can you [edit] the question to reduce this to a [mcve] – remove the successful Elasticsearch output, replace the Dockerfiles with Compose `image:`, and so on?

Comment: It is a microservices project and I have multiple apps. They all talk to each but the only one having a problem is zipkin